# How to hide a column of a DataTabe dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a DataTable with 12 columns in Flutter.  I would like to hide certain columns based on user's filter selection.

[image]

I tried to set the Container width inside a DataCell to zero and empty the contents, but there is still an empty space occupying a certain width in the table.

```
        DataCell(Container(
            width: TableTitles[2].width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Styles.TableRow(rec.respond, TextAlign.center))),


Widget TableRow(_content, _align, [_color]){
  return Container(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Text(_content,
        textAlign: _align,
        style: SetTableRowStyle(16, _color),
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

TableTitles[2].width is set to 0, and rec.respond is clearer.